# After many Form data are submitted to php file, How can the php file receive that data input?

Tags: php, jquery

My html code - in the form structure, has 1 data-role="collapsible-set" and many data-role="collapsible".  has many checkbox as like below code.

```
 <form action="sx_oriented.php" method="get" id="symptom">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
              <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3>Circulatory and Respiratory systems? Click me!</h3>

                   <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="symptom">Select your Symptoms</label>
        <table>                      
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R00"></th><th> Abnormalities of heart beat</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R00.0"></th><th> Tachycardia, unspecified</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R00.1"></th><th> Bradycardia, unspecified</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R00.2"></th><th> Palpitations</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R00.8"></th><th> Other and unspecified abnormalities of heart beat</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R01"></th><th> Cardiac murmurs and other cardiac sounds</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R01.0"></th><th> Benign and innocent cardiac murmurs</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R01.1"></th><th> Cardiac murmur, unspecified</th></tr>
       </table>
       </div> 

       <div data-role="collapsible">
              <h3>Digestive system and abdomen? Click me!</h3>

                              <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <label for="r_code[]">Select r_code[]</label>
         <table>
             <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10"></th><th> Abdominal and pelvic pain</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.0"></th><th> Acute abdomen</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.1"></th><th> Pain localized to upper abdomen</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.10"></th><th> Abdomen pain, Right upper quadrant</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.11"></th><th> Abdomen pain, Left upper quadrant</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.12"></th><th> Epigastric pain</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.19"></th><th> Upper abdominal pain, unspecified</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.2"></th><th> Pelvic and perineal pain</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.3"></th><th> Pain localized to other parts of lower abdomen</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.30"></th><th> Abdomen pain, Right lower quadrant</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.31"></th><th> Abdomen pain, Left lower quadrant</th></tr>
        <tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="r_code[]"  value="R10.32"></th><th> Periumbilical pain</th></tr>
       </table>
      </div>
          ----10 more "collapsible"---
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
```

and then, action="sx_oriented.php" that source code as like below

```
    <?php
    $checked = $_GET['r_code'];
    for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
   echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
   }
   ?>
```

but, I have no result!
why not??
Please, help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would use `POST` in my form. So change `method="get"` to `method="POST"`.

Then you can do this.

```
<?php

    $checked = $_POST['r_code'];

    if(isset($checked)){
      foreach($checked as $check){
      echo "Selected ".$check."<br />"; 
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Teacher Pjack, i changed get to post method as you wrote. And i changed my php code, but had no result.

Comment: In Form fields, any other problems that have many collapsible input checKbox data??

Comment: Your answer is correct in simple form data. But,  If jQuery exists in form structure,, the form data don't reach the php file. I don't know Why??